# Optional("Operation in progress.") when using HomeKit to add accessory on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Xcode 7.2 with HomeKit Accessory Simulator Version 1.3 (77.1)

I have the following code in my HomeKit code

```
//MARK: UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let accessory = accessories[indexPath.row] as HMAccessory

    if let room = homeManager.primaryHome?.rooms.first as HMRoom? {
        homeManager.primaryHome?.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Issues adding accessory to home. \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.homeManager.primaryHome?.assignAccessory(accessory, toRoom: room, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Issues adding accessory to room. \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I click on the UITableViewCell, it brings up the Add Accessory dialog and after I enter the pairing / setup code, it gives me the error :

> Issues adding accessory to home. Optional("Operation in progress.")

At other times I get

> Issues adding accessory to home. Optional("Client request error when
>   communicating with accessory.")

When I run the same code on iPhone (iOS 9.2.1) I get the following error

> Something went wrong when attempting to create our home.
>   Optional("Cloud data sync is in progress.")

Is this is a known issue in HomeKit? Or is it a bug in the HomeKit Hardware Simulator? Is there a workaround / fix?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to change

```
if let room = homeManager.primaryHome?.rooms.first as HMRoom? {
```

to

```
if let room = homeManager.primaryHome?.rooms.first as? HMRoom {
```

if I'm reading this code correctly?

---

But it would be more readable - and debuggable - if the conditions were separated and if you used the unwrapped object. Assuming HMRoom is a class:

```
if let home = homeManager.primaryHome,
    room = home.rooms.first as? HMRoom {
    home.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Issues adding accessory to home. \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            home.assignAccessory(accessory, toRoom: room, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Issues adding accessory to room. \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```